# ¿como pasar un parametro a un método desde la vista con .net framework?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

soy nuevo con esto de .net framework y tengo la siguiente duda. Tengo una vista que muestra unos datos en una tabla, necesito generar un método que coja los datos de la columna hourlySalary y haga lo sigiente: 120 * HourlySalary * 12 . Pero ese no es mi problema, la cuestion es que no se como enviar los datos de la columna al metodo correspondiente desde la vista.

```
<table class="table" id="Data">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.contractTypeName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.roleId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.roleName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.roleDescripcion)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.hourlySalary)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.monthlySalary)
            </th>
            <th>

            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr class="info">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contractTypeName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.roleId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.roleName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.roleDescripcion)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.hourlySalary)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.monthlySalary)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!--aqui retornar el valor del metodo que debe hacer la operacion-->
                </td>


            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>
```

De antemano muchas gracias a quienes me puedan ayudar y quedo atento.

Comment: Quieres hacer ese calculo y mostrarlo en otra columna solamente? Porque si es asi, con Javascript o JQuery te bastaria :)

Comment: Hola, ya que eres nuevo en ASP.NET MVC, te aconsejo aprendas algo antes de cómo enviar datos desde una Vista a un Controlador. Te recomiendo la lectura del siguiente artículo:  [Cómo recibir datos desde un formulario POST en ASP.NET MVC](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2018/10/14/c%C3%B3mo-recibir-datos-desde-un-formulario-post-en-aspnet-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

puedes crear una propiedad de solo lectura que haga el calculo.

```
public decimal propiedadCalculada {
     get
     {
        return 120 * HourlySalary * 12;
     }
}
```

Despues solamente usas esa propiedad en la vista

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.propiedadCalculada )
```